# How to use bash substitution to append a newline at the end of each element of a list

Tags: bash

I am looking for a bash one liner that appends a newline after each element of a list. If I call the script as:

```
./script arg1 arg2 arg3
```

I want the output to be

```
arg1
arg2
arg3
```

I tried different variations of the following. The newline does not get added. Any ordinary char gets added.

```
# pretty much works except for an extra space
list=${@/%/x}
echo "$list"

# appends 'n'
list=${@/%/\n}
echo "$list"

# appends nothing
list=${@/%/$'\n'}
echo "$list"

# appends nothing, \x078 would append 'x'
list=${@/%/$'\x0D'}
echo "$list"

# appends nothing
CR=$'\n'
list=${@/%/$CR}
echo "$list"

# same issues with arrays
tmp=($@)
list=${tmp/%/\n}
echo "$list"
```

What fix or alternative do you suggest? I obviously could write a loop or call tr but that's precisely what I thought I could avoid with a bash substitution.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid a loop? That may make the code unnecessarily complicated. As a general rule, don't try to be as clever as possible and keep stuff simple - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle .

Comment: Because I want to take advantage of the language expressiveness. KISS is good for avoiding unnecessary complexity. What is the complexity of reformatting a list of arguments?

Comment: Regarding the _appends nothing part_: use quotes: `list="${@/%/$'\n'}"; echo "$list"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this function with `"$@"`:

```
f() { printf "%s\n" "$@"; }
f arg1 arg2 arg3
arg1
arg2
arg3
```

As per `man bash`

```
 @   Expands  to  the positional parameters, starting from one.  When the expansion occurs
     within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word.  That is, "$@" is
     equivalent to "$1" "$2" ...
```

Comment: Neat! I guess I focused too much on a substitution to think about printf. I'd still like to know why substitution does not work, if someone cares to answer that part.

Comment: You don't to wrap printf inside a function btw. printf alone works very well since "$@" is expanded first.

Comment: Yes that is true, I used function just for code demo purpose. Intent was always to use `printf`. To answer your first question you could use: `s="$@"; echo "${s// /$'\n'}";` for **substitution**.

Comment: `"${@// /$'\n'}"` is ok if args do not contain spaces. `"${@/%/$'\n'}"` works except for a space appearing in front of 2nd arg and following. Anyways that's good enough. My `$'\n'` did not expand because of missing quotes. Thanks for that too!

Answer (score 2):

printf would have been my answer as well. Another technique is to use `IFS`:

```
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ list="$*"
$ echo "$list"
arg1
arg2
arg3
```

Notes:

- uses [ANSI-C](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) quoting for the newline sequence
- `"$*"` ([with the quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters), crucial) joins the positional params using the first char of $IFS
- quote the shell variable for the echo command to preserve the inner newlines.

That redefines the IFS value for the current shell. You can save the old value first and restore it after:

```
oldIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; list="$*"; IFS=$oldIFS
```

or you can use a subshell so the modification is discarded for you:

```
$ list=$( IFS=$'\n'; echo "$*" )
```